In Bash, Multiple Substring before Specific Char and Continue with
I am trying to write a regex that can satisfy the following condition.

first, string will be start with multiple substrings --> ^(aa|bb|cc)
second, then multiple substring it has to be continue with specified chars . (dot) or @ (at) --> ^(aa|bb|cc) [.@]
third, after specified chars, it has to be contain at least one occurence charsets includes [a-zA-Z0-9_] charsets or at least one occurence any charset except .@

EXAMPLES:
string | matched
----------------
aa.xya -> true
aa.    -> false
aa     -> false
--------
bb.@b  -> false
bb@b   -> true
bb.b   -> true
---------
cc.bb. -> false
cc.bb@ -> false
cc.xz  -> true 
...
...
...

I need to a $PATTERN that contains all state, so what should my $PATTERN be?
if [[ "$string" =~ $PATTERN ]] 


You shouldn't have a space before [.@]

For the last part, just use [^.@]. That includes everything in [a-zA-Z0-9_], so you don't have to check for that specifically.

You're close. You shouldn't have a space between (aa|bb|cc) and [.@]. For the third part, use [^.@]+$` to match at least one character not in this charset continuing to the end.
^(aa|bb|cc)[.@][^.@]+$

DEMO
In the demo I added \n to the last part so it doesn't match newlines. That shouldn't matter for your use if $string is just one line.

thank u @Barmar for the last, can instead of + operator can u limit it min to max number

Of course you can. What's preventing you from trying, or looking at the documentation?

@IchigoKurosaki replace it with {1,10} to limit to 10.
